# CakePHP 2.0 Security::cipher result not being saved

Tags: cakephp

I am attempting to encrypt some data in beforeSave method of my model. But it is not being saved.

```
       $currentBalance = $this->find("all", array(
            "fields" => array(
                "SUM(base_amount) as 'CurrentBalance'"
            ),
            "conditions" => array(
                "Payment.user_id" => $this->data["Payment"]["user_id"]
            )
        ));

        $this->log($this->data["Payment"]);
        $this->log(Configure::read("Security.salt"));        
        $this->log(Security::cipher(implode("|", $this->data["Payment"]), Configure::read("Security.cipherSeed")));

        $this->set("balance", $currentBalance[0][0]["CurrentBalance"] + $this->data["Payment"]["base_amount"]);
        $this->set("balance_checksum", Security::cipher(implode("|", $this->data["Payment"]), Configure::read("Security.salt")));
```

If I look at the log file I get some sort of encrypted data but it's all giberish.

Whilst in the database I get absolutely nothing.

If I replace the cipher function with a simple string say "123" ... that's gets saved correctly.

I have made sure that the database connection is utf8 encoded and the fields in the database have a utf8 collation.

Any pointers on this would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I have gone on a problem that was similar. The problem was that ciphering data was creating some invalid utf8 characters. Such as chinese characters and stuff. What I did is converting the ciphered string to hexadecimal then saving. And when getting the data back you decode from hexa to characters and then decipher it.

(In AppModel.php)

```
<?php
/**
 * Encrypts a sensible string for the bd
 * @param string $toEncrypt
 * @return string  encrypted hexadecimal 
 */
function encryptCipher($toEncrypt) {
    $CipherKey = Configure::read('Security.cipherSeed');
    return bin2hex(Security::cipher($toEncrypt, $CipherKey));
}
?>
```

(In AppController.php) the decrypt method, where $this->CipherKey is loaded in the __construct in the exact same way as the model

```
<?php function __construct(){
$this->CipherKey = Configure::read('Security.cipherSeed');
}

/**
 * The main decrypting function
 * 
 * @param string $strToDecrypt the string to be decrypted
 * @return string the decrypted string 
 */
public function decryptCipher($strToDecrypt) {
    return Security::cipher(pack("H*", $strToDecrypt), $this->CipherKey);
}
?>
```